Open a recent PDF created in Android
I'm using Android Studio to make a simple app to create some PDF files to store some data. I wanto just to make an intent for the generated PDF auto opens for the user.
Here's just the canvas drawing sonme text and saving the PDF on Downloads. Working fine
canvas.drawText(text ,x ,y, paint);
        document.finishPage(page);
        File downloadsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        String fileName = "document.pdf";
        File file = new File(downloadsDir, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            document.writeTo(fos);
            document.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        showPdf();

Here's my attempt to open the generated file
public void showPdf() {
        try {

            File downloadsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            String fileName = "document.pdf";
            File file = new File(downloadsDir, fileName);

            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

The app runs fine, no crashes. But nothing happens after the PDF generation.

Do you have any PDF viewer app installed?

For those who needs a future help, I've managed to get the code working with a lot of changes. It works both for sharing the file (and the user can use it to print or share via any app isntalled) or you can change to view, but in that case you'll need a PDF viwer app. Tested both inAVD and a real phone. Here's it now:
public void showPdf() {
    try {

        File downloadsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        String fileName = originalNameFile;
        File file = new File(downloadsDir, fileName);

        Uri uri;
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.pdffiles.fileProvider", file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share File"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

